# How to rewrite the lower bound and upper bound of the double sum to accommodate a constraint?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How to rewrite the upper bound and lower bound of this double sum:

$$\sum\limits_{K = 0}^{K = M - 1} {\sum\limits_{L = 0}^{L = M - 1} {f\left( {{x_L},{x_K}} \right)} }$$

When the summation process can only be proceeded under the constraint $K + 1 > L$ ?

Since $M$ could be very large, for example the number of antenna in Massive MIMO system dropping the conditional checking of $K + 1 > L$ can save a little bit time.

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it as

$$\sum_{L=0}^{M-1}\sum_{K=L}^{M-1}f(x_L,x_K)$$

or as

$$\sum_{K=0}^{M-1}\sum_{L=0}^Kf(x_L,x_K)\,;$$

both are equivalent to

$$\sum_{0\le L\le K\le M-1}f(x_L,x_K)\,.$$

Comment: Thank you very much your result work very well. May I ask for the summation change for an extra case of $K+2>L$, my guess would be $\sum\limits_{K = 0}^{K = M - 1} {\sum\limits_{L = 0}^{L = K + 1} {} }$.  Do we need to plot the region of summation like when we do the change or integration order ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh: You’re very welcome. Yes, that would work. And plotting the region of summation as one does for changing the order of integration can be very helpful, though with practice one comes to recognize the most common situations.

Comment: For those who read this section, I have make a mistake. For the case $K+2>L$ the summation would be $\sum\limits_{K = 0}^{K = M - 1} {\sum\limits_{L = 0}^{L = K + 1\backslash \{ L = M\} } {} }$ where I discard 1 element